# Avahi Daemon not resolving (dot)local addresses if queried from different computer

Tags: linux, windows, mdns, avahi

I have two machines, one is Antergos (Arch/Linux) and the other one is Windows 10 connected to each other using **LAN**. The Antergos PC has a hostname of *niffler* and the Windows PC has a hostname of *phoenix*. The IP addresses to both the PCs are assigned by my router and they don't change too often. But still I want to use these PCs using their *hostnames* instead of their IPs. So I installed `avahi` and `nss-mdns` on *niffler* from the [official](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/avahi) Arch Wiki and also did everything they mentioned. To double check that I did everything correctly, I `ping`ed *niffler* (`ping niffler.local`) using it's own terminal session and it resolved to it's correct IP. However when I use *phoenix* to `ping` to *niffler*, it doesn't work. When I run `ping niffler.local` from *phoenix*, it gives the error - `Ping request could not find niffler.local. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: Are you running a mDNS daemon/service on the Windows machine? Did you open the mDNS port in the firewall?

Comment: I installed Bonjour on Windows 10 machine. Now it works, but it's not resolving address through web browsers. I've hosted a `nodejs` website on *niffler* but can't connect to it using *phoenix* with a web browser.